# Перегрузить оператор &

Tags: c++, ооп, перегрузка-операторов

Определить операцию над векторами:
& формирование нового вектора так, что каждый элемент нового вектора определяется следующим образом:c[i] = (a[i] > b[i]) ? a[i]: b[i].

В общем, как я понял нужно, чтобы при выполнении vector3 = vector1 & vector2, в vector 3 находились наибольшие значение массива. Например, если vector1 = [1,2,3], а vector2 = [4,0,1], то vector3 должен содержать [4,2,3].

Я додумался до такой реализации, но, если я здесь, понятно, что у меня не получилось:

```
Vector& Vector::operator&(const Vector& obj)
{
    if (vectorSize = obj.vectorSize)
    {
        this->ptrArr = new int[vectorSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++)
        {
            if (this->ptrArr[i] > obj.ptrArr[i])
            {
                return *this;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Наставьте на путь истинный кому не сложно.

1. Что будет если размеры массивов не равны я просто не дописал, это не сильно к делу относится.
2. Реализация массива

   ```
   void Vector::SetVector()
   {
       srand(time(NULL));
       for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++)
       {
           ptrArr[i] = rand() % 1000;
           Sleep(500);
       }
   ```
3. Вобщем, создаётся три рандомно заполненных массива, и, как я выше написал, нужно, чтобы в третьем были наибольшие значения из первых двух. Для реализации этого нужно перегрузить знак &.

Comment: 1. А если массивы не равны? 2. Где у Вас заполнение результирующего массива? 3. Что у Вас в цикле написано - я вообще не понял Вашу задумку....

Comment: `this->ptrArr = new int[vectorSize];` - здесь вы убили предшествующее состояния вектора (this). Очевидно, нужно вернуть новый экземпляр вектора, а не менять состояние текущего.

Comment: По условию должен формироваться новый вектор.

Comment: поставьте, пожалуйста, стрелочку вверх на ответ @Harry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поскольку у вас ничего не сказано о внутреннем представлении `Vector`, приходится только гадать о нем. Так что я покажу, как бы я делал для

```
using Vector = vector<int>;
```

Это был бы не член класса, а свободная функция:

```
Vector operator&(const Vector& a, const Vector& b)
{
    if (a.size() != b.size()) throw runtime_error("a.size() != b.size()");
    Vector c(a.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        c[i] = a[i] > b[i] ? a[i] : b[i];
    return c;
}
```

Вот полная программа - https://ideone.com/RsL4rf

Ну, а вы уж попробуйте переписать для своего вектора...

Comment: Спасибо, Harry, как всегда ты вовремя